# Iterative Processing for make NetCDF table View in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4, netcdf

I am trying to process NetCDF file using Make NetCDF view table but do not understand where it stores output?

I have 32 nc file for which I am using ModelBuilder.

[image]

Comment: A view is normally temporary so it is only stored in memory. Use Copy Rows or Copy Table to make it permanent. Use `Name` in output name, for example `C:\somedatabase.gdb\%Name%` to name after input file name

Comment: it has done thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Normally temporary file stored in memory. If you want to add any other process just drag-and-drop in Model Builder window and creates the connection of each module.